# Silex : allow user to change langage by clicking on html element and keeping clean URL

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, silex

I am using Silex and Twig for a website and I want to allow the user to change the langage of the site.

### My problem

Right now, it works if I change the locale in the URL :

`/my-account`: my page content is in English (default _locale)

`/fr/my-account`: my page content is in French

`/en/my-account`: my page content is in English

**How can I do the do the same by clicking on an html element?**

I am looking for some idea to solve my problem and some good practice to do this "the right way" if possible.

### My code

Here is the Silex component I use to manage the multilangue :

```
// TRANSLATION
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider());
$app->register(new \Pmaxs\Silex\Locale\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider(), [
    'locale.locales' => ['en', 'fr'],
    'locale.default_locale' => 'en',
    'locale.resolve_by_host' => false,
    'locale.exclude_routes' => ['^_']
]);
$app->extend('translator', function($translator, $app) {
    $translator->addLoader('yaml', new YamlFileLoader());

    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__.'/../src/locales/en.yml', 'en');
    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__.'/../src/locales/fr.yml', 'fr');

    return $translator;
});
```

Here is my html for the user to change the langage:

```
<li id="drop-langue" data-lg="en">
    <span id="current-lg">EN</span> // My current langue
    <div class="drop-langue">
        // The list of langage the user can choose : here ONE -> FR
        <div id="list_langue">
          <a class="change_langue" href="#" data-lg="fr"> <span>FR</span></a> // Could be nice to change the langue staying on the same page
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Now my jQuery to get the value :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".change_langue").on("click", function() {
        var new_langue = $(this).data("lg");

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('new-langue') }}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'langue': new_langue},
            success: function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My Ajax controller :

```
$app->match('/new-langue', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $new_langue = $request->get('langue');

    // some code to change the langage

    return New Response($new_langue);
})->bind('new-langue');
```

If I do this, my Ajax success `console.log(resp);` give me `en` as I want.

### Some ideas / questions about how to do it

1. Is it a good idea to do it with an Ajax call?
2. If I change `fr` by `en` in my url it works, is it a good idea to try to do it in javascript using `window.location.href` for example? (I think not but still asking)
3. I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034947/silex-redirect-changing-the-locale) for an other problem and try it in my controller but I get this error : `500 (Internal Server Error)` (I did the same, with `$new_langue` instead of `$app['defaultLanguage']` and with the right name for my homepage).

It's the first time I create a full website with Silex and I'm beginner with php framework so if someone can help to achieve what I want...thanks by advance !

**EDIT :**

According to the anwser I get and what I want to achieve, is it possible to change the locale and staying in the same page with Silex / Twig?

For example, this give me the current route : `global.request.get('_route')` and this `global.request.get('_locale')` give me the locale.

If I take the example of my Home Page, this is how my controller look right now (I just show the template) :

```
$app->match('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('home.html.twig');
})->bind('home');
```

As you can see, I have no {_locale} param in my URL. **So can I keep this "clean URL" without the {_locale} and make a click that stay in the same page + change the current langage?**

I'd like to make somehting like this : `<a href="{{ path(global.request.get('_route')), global.request.set('_locale', 'FR') }}">FR</a>`

But it won't work for sure...can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a solution to do what I want, using `pmaxs/silex-locale` (https://github.com/pmaxs/silex-locale).

As I said in my question, I already used it for my translation but I didn't used the "Url generation" as I should...So here is a recap of how to use it (read the documentation if you use Silex v1.x):

**1/ Loading Provider**

```
$app->register(new \Pmaxs\Silex\Locale\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider(), [
    'locale.locales' => ['en', 'fr'],  //I want to translate my site in English and French
    'locale.default_locale' => 'en',   // By default, the locale is "en"
    'locale.resolve_by_host' => false,
    'locale.exclude_routes' => ['^_']
]);
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider());
```

**2/ Usage**

Here is my home route controller :

```
// this page is accessible by urls '/', '/fr/' or '/en/'
$app->match('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    // my code

     return $app['twig']->render('home.html.twig');
})->bind('home');
```

As you can see, I have no `{_locale}` variable in my routing, but still can use it to change the langage of my page.

**3/ Url generator**

Now, here is how I change my langage :

```
{% set locale_list = ["en", "fr"] %} // the list of all langage in my website
{% set current_locale = global.request.getLocale() %} // the current langage of my page

<li id="drop-langue">
    // I display the current langage
    <span id="current-lg">{{ current_locale|upper }}</span> 
    <div class="drop-langue">
        <div id="list_langue">
            {% for locale in locale_list %}
                {% if locale != current_locale %}
                    // I create one link to change the langage according to all the langage I want, minus the current langage
                    <a class="change_langue" href="{{ locale_generate(locale , global.request.get('_route')) }}" >
                        <span>{{ locale|upper }}</span>
                    </a>
                 {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
         </div>
     </div>
 </li>
```

I'm using the "Url Generator", it works like this : `locale_generate('es', $name, $parameters = array(), $referenceType = UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH)` (more details in the documentation).

This way, when I come in my website I'm in english (my default locale) with my "clean Url" `/`. Then by clicking on `FR` my url become `/fr/` and my content is translate in French with a new selection menu (current-langue = FR and I can select "EN").

Answer (score 4):

So, from your message, i can extract your goal is to *allow the language to be changed when you click on an HTML element*.

The usage of the *a* tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another and can be used to achieve what you want.

I've done multilang sites previously and you can achieve this in a variety of ways.

///////////////////////////////**Method 1:** define the location in the HTML attribute href

In your HTML code you've used hash - # within the hyperlink .

Hyperlinks require the href property, because it specifies a location.

Looking at your code, you have the  tag but it's missing the link to the specific location you want to redirect the user to.

Let's say you want it to go to `my-account` page in french.

So, your HTML code should be:

```
<li id="drop-langue" data-lg="en">
    <span id="current-lg">EN</span> // My current langue
    <div class="drop-langue">
        // The list of langage the user can choose : here ONE -> FR
        <div id="list_langue">
          <a class="change_langue" href="http://yourwebsite.com/fr/my-account" data-lg="fr"><span>FR</span></a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**To note:** substitute *yourwebsite.com* with your website's domain.

///////////////////////////////**end of Method 1**

In your HTML code you mention `// Could be nice to change the langue staying on the same page`.

That can be done using AJAX, yes.

But I don't suggest you to do that because from looking at bigger companies that also have websites in multiple languages such as [SAP](https://www.sap.com/portugal/index.html) or [Apple](https://www.apple.com/) they all redirect to a different page.

///////////////////////////////**UPDATE:** the answer until now was created because I thought your need was simply to allow the language to be changed when you click on an HTML element.

Apparently, your goal is slightly more complex than that.

Accordingly to Silex documentation, the usage of `_locale` is [the way to go](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/translation.html).

In [this question you can see working code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502805/silex-and-twig-localization):

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views',
));

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(array(
    'locale_fallbacks' => array('hr'),
)));


$app['translator'] = $app->share($app->extend('translator', function($translator) {

    $translator->addLoader('xlf', new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader());

    $translator->addResource('xlf', __DIR__.'/../locales/hr.xlf', 'hr');
    $translator->addResource('xlf', __DIR__.'/../locales/en.xlf', 'en');
    $translator->addResource('xlf', __DIR__.'/../locales/sl.xlf', 'sl');

    return $translator;
}));


$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {

    $app['translator']->setLocale('hr');

    return $app['twig']->render('home.twig', array('d' => $app['translator']->getLocale()));

});


$app->get('/{_locale}/', function() use ($app) {
    $app['translator']->setLocale($app['request']->get('locale'));

    return $app['twig']->render('home.twig', array('d' => $app['translator']->getLocale()));
});



$app->run();
```

Comment: Ok so your anwser is : just change the locale in the URL? I will try it tomorrow at work ! I'm not sure it's the best practice but it should work for sure :)

Comment: As I said in the other comment, I use Twig (I didn't say it clearly sorry, the path() function in my Ajax url wasn't enough), I edited my question to be more precise about what I try to do !

Comment: Mickael, the question got really confusing, needs to be edited for clarity

Comment: As I said in my last edit, my routes in my controller don't have the `_locale` variable. I'd like to use your idea + keep my URL clean to change the langage. I can make a click and stay on the same page but I didn't resolve my problem to switch langage without using this locale variable...so I'd like to know if it's possible or if I will need to add the `_locale` ?

Comment: see the update on the answer result of question updates.. I hope to answer your question now

Comment: I'm not sure your edit solve my problem at 100% but you still give me the best advice and I have a better idea of how to do what I want, so I will give you the bounty :) Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1):

In you case its just the matter of adding proper links to allow users so they can switch language. Rest of the work is already done by you. The language switcher dropdown must contain all supported languages including English. See below am example image.

[image]

Instead of redirecting the users to `http://yourwebsite.com/[fr]/my-account` you must redirect to a special method like `http://www.yourwebsite.com/language_change?lang=fr`. You will get `HTTP_REFERRER` in `$_SERVER` variable so you can redirect users back to the original page they were at. This way you can preserve users current visiting page/url.

Secondly, Ajax vs Redirect: Its better to use a redirect instead of AJAX. If you use AJAX you will increase the complicity to yourself.

When working with multilingual website, we must follow these best practices.

- Specific routes per language
- Menus, labels and forms
- The content of the website
- Extra: translate FOSUserBundle

Comment: I didn't say it (I edited my question, sorry) but I am using Twig (the {{path()}} in my Ajax url could have be a clue !), so I use `href="{{path('my_route_name'}}", so no `lang=fr` (this way I know how to do this with some session variable. I edited what I wanted to do according to the anwser I got !

Comment: @MickaelLeger - Great to hear. I posted my answer because wanted to bring into your notice that the users current url must be preserved when they change language. :)

Comment: Sure, as I said in the introduction of my question, my translation works fine : `/my-page`, `/en/my-page` = english content and `/fr/my-page` = french content. My controller has no `/{_locale}` in the path so I can't do `href={{ path(global.request.get('_route'), {_locale : 'fr'} ) }}`, any idea how to do and still have `/my-page` but with the locale variable the user choose?

Comment: Yeah I saw it, I tried it but I have `?_locale=fr`at the end of my URL and still the same content langage...I think I will have to keep this solution and add `{_locale}` in my routing to make it works

Comment: I think you are right. Check this one also. http://phpbeginnertoadvanced.blogspot.in/2016/09/multilingual-website-with-symfony.html

Answer (score 0):

The simple idea here is: how your application determines the language to be used to render the pages.

**solution #1** *(your current solution)* based on a URL parameter (that's `_locale` ), and fallback to some default value in case no URL-parameter given.
So in this solution the translation component always looks for the selected language in the parameters bag prepared by the router component.

**Solution #2** put your language identifier inside a session variable.
 Your `/new-langue` page will have to set this session variable with the value it receives. and your router will populate the `_locale` parameter from that session variable.

I may be able to provide some code snippets a bit later.